# Access original raw headers with WSGI

Tags: python, http-headers, wsgi, request-headers

So lets say you have a WSGI handler:

```
def handle_request(environ, start_response):
```

The headers in environ should be something like

```
{'HTTP_HOST': 'localhost:8080', 'HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/..'}
```

WSGI turns "User-Agent" and "user_agent" into "HTTP_USER_AGENT", but I need the exact original name.

Are there ANY way to access the original headers / request text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not. As per the WSGI specification the headers are passed per CGI naming rules.

Perhaps actually describe the underlying problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I need to forward (proxy) certain types of requests to another server while trying to keep them identical to the original request (which means no underscored headers).

Comment: So reverse things back to what they were. HTTP headers are case insensitive so it doesn't matter if you don't know the case. You also should not really be using any non alphabetic characters besides dash, so any underscore always goes to dash. And obviously don't forget to strip HTTP_ from start. See implementation of http://pythonpaste.org/modules/proxy.html for how it does it.